# "Ignore" quotes in positional parameters in my Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I have a script  that has SMS forwarded to it and posts  some of that data to a PHP script. Below is my Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to post data to Top up processor
curl  --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1/user//topup/process.php' --data "receipt=$1" --data "username=$9"
```

So to run it:

```
./mpesa_topup.sh sms_message
```

But the SMS server forwards the message with single quotes:

```
./mpesa_topup.sh 'sms_message'
```

The script ends up "parsing the entire SMS as 1 positional parameter. Here is a debug of what happens when the sms server runs the script.

```
root@sms:/var/lib/playsms/sms_command/1# bash -x mpesa_topup.sh 'JJA88QHC22 Confirmed.on 101015 at 9:49 PMKsh25.00 received from 254712345678 SOME BODY.New Account balance is Ksh25.00'
+ curl --request POST http://10.5.1.2/topup/process.php --data 'receipt=JJA88QHC22 Confirmed.on 101015 at 9:49 PMKsh25.00 received from 254722227332 JOTHAM KIIRU.New Account balance is Ksh25.00' --data username=
root@sms:/var/lib/playsms/sms_command/1#
```

Is there a way to remove/ignore the opening and closing single quotes in the Bash script?

PS : I am not a coder, gotten where I am with help from my friend Google.

Comment: Don't put quotes around it when you invoke it, if you put quotes around it when you invoke the command then the quotes mean "treat this is a single parameter"  If you don't put quotes, word splitting occurs to assign positional parameters

Comment: when you dbl-quoted a variable, as you have done with `--data "receipt=$1"`, when you use shell debug `(set -x)`, The shell "normalizes" all quoting to the "final" representation that it is  executing, hence the use of single-quotes in the debug output. So if you don't want any quotes around your `--data "receipt=$1"`, then remove them. Even if you quoted escaped spaces inside of `$1` with the '\' char, the `set -x` will show that variable as quoted w single-quotes. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you want the first and ninth word out of the single argument you are sent. You can do something like this:

```
$ set --  'JJA88QHC22 Confirmed.on 101015 at 9:49 PMKsh25.00 received from 254712345678 SOME BODY.New Account balance is Ksh25.00'
$ echo $1
JJA88QHC22 Confirmed.on 101015 at 9:49 PMKsh25.00 received from 254712345678 SOME BODY.New Account balance is Ksh25.00

$ set -f      # a
$ set -- $1   # b
$ set +f      # c

$ echo $1
JJA88QHC22
$ echo $9
254712345678
```

The key is (b) where we *omit the double quotes* around the variable. This allows the shell to perform word-splitting on the value of the variable.

The shell will also attempt to perform glob-pattern expansion, unless you tell it not to, which I do in (a), and then turn that back on in (c).

Comment: Using `read` would work for this also. Either manually or with `-a`. But all of these solutions assume that internal spaces can *never* happen.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I now have automated WiFi billing. I will by you a beer.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this simply by putting your main command inside a function, and calling it again.

Your server is invoking your script with simple quotes, which transform your arguments in one single argument ($1).

If you treat this arg and call your_function() inside the script, you solved!

Here goes the example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to post data to Top up processor
args=$1

your_function(){
  curl  --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1/user//topup/process.php' --data "receipt=$1" --data "username=$9"
  }
your_function $1
```

Comment: This seems like a long way to go to just not quote the argument list in the first place, but could get the job done I guess

Comment: Yes Eric, I agree.. your 'not quote' is the best solution if mymanga has access to change the invocation of the script... I've suggested the function because sometimes a root crontab in a superior server administration tier is who's invoking... and user just have access to the script itself.. By the way both will work. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but that won't help. In the end, your code passes the whole SMS as a single string to `curl` because of `--data "receipt=$1"`. If you only remove the quotes, that would become `--data "receipt=JJA88QHC22"` and the rest (like the amount) would be missing.

Your problem is that the input was multiple lines of text and that got somehow mangled. The solution is to parse the SMS. Since money is involved, you probably don't want any mistakes. That's why I would use a real programming language like Python or Java. But if you want to use BASH, this might work until an attacker starts sending you SMS to steal money:

```
# Split first parameter into $1...$n
set -- $1

recepient="$1"
# $2: Confirmed.on
# $3: 101015
# $4: at
# $5: 9:49
# $6: PMKsh25.00
amount=$(echo $6 | sed -e s/^(AM|PM)//) # sed removed the AM/PM at the beginning
# $7: received
# $8: from
sender="$7 $8 $9" # 254722227332 JOTHAM KIIRU.
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I am using bash because that is what the sms server supports. And the there's no worry about attackers because I'm using a special simcard that only receives confirmation sms for payments made directly from the telco. I only need the receipt number and phone number to forward to the billing system... That's why the script is so simplistic. Just need a way to have it read the receipt number and phone number. And again .. I am not a coder.. Been googling for days to get where I am. Just need to have the bash script ignore the first and last single quotes - mpesa.sh 'sms_message'